# How to convert plain text into feature/value pair format

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

I checked various svm classifier, which uses feature/value pair format for classification purpose. (I am focusing on svmlight - http://svmlight.joachims.org/) format is like this :

```
-1 1:0.43 3:0.12 9284:0.2 # abcdef
```

But as I am getting user input in form of plain text, to classify it using svmlight, I need to convert plain text to this format.

how it could be done?

Comment: Cannot you do tf-idf on your input text and write a script to transform the result into libsvm format?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use some **real valued embeeding**. In other words, you have data in the space of texts, which is more or less space of varied length sequences of words. There are numerous approaches, one better for one purpose, and other - for another, the most simple ones include:

- encode on word level, so each word is a "dimension", so in your case - you create a dictionary of words and assign each word a consequtive integer. Now each document can be encoded as a vector, where each feature's value is for example "if the word is in the document" (set of words) or maybe "how many times does it word occur" (bag of words; also known as term frequency, tf) or some more complex statistics (like for example tf-idf; term frequency multiplied by inverted document frequency).
- encode on level of ngrams, similarly to the previous one, but instead of enumerating each word you enumerate each n-gram (n-gram is any sequence of n-words), this is more syntatical feature, but requires significantly more data to train on.
- use some "magical encoding" or specialistic "string kernels".

First two approaches can be easily done using scikit-learn's tfidf vectorizer, see http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html . The last one requires more complex software.